# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, 2)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm new to tensorflow and trying to create a linear regression model. My code is

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

bias = np.ones((50, 1))
trainX = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2).reshape(50, 1)
trainY = (3 * trainX + np.random.rand(trainX.shape[0]) * 20 - 10) + 10
trainX = np.append(bias, trainX, axis=1)

X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(1, 2))
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
w = tf.Variable([[0.0, 0.0]], name="weights")

model = tf.matmul(X, tf.transpose(w))
cost = tf.pow((Y - model), 2)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(50):
        for (x, y) in zip(trainX, trainY):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

    print(sess.run(w))
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think the problem is in initializing weights. The idea is simple to predict two weight constants which best predict the line fitting the data.

[I'm getting this error in colaboratory notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcje.png)

Comment: Which tensorflow version do you use? With tensorflow 1.8 your code runs after reshaping x to have `(1, 2)` shape.

Comment: my tensorflow version is 1.9.0. I'm using it colab notebook provided by google. well I tried reshaping x to (1,2) by adding x = x.reshape(1,2) in for loop, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AliDanish What do you mean by "it still doesn't work"? That should solve your original problem regarding the mismatched shapes. Now, this may not solve other possible problems in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are conspiring here. I assume that you want the shape of `trainY` to be `(50,)`, but since you add the noise only after reshaping, broadcasting causes `trainX + np.random.rand(trainX.shape[0])` to have shape `(50, 50)`. If you change the initial part of the code to

```
bias = np.ones(50)
trainX = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
trainY = (3 * trainX + np.random.rand(trainX.shape[0]) * 20 - 10) + 10
trainX = np.vstack([bias, trainX]).T
```

and ensure that the shapes are set up properly through

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x.reshape((1, 2)), Y: y})
```

then your code will run.

However, since you are only dealing with the inner product of 2-dimensional vectors, you can avoid the reshaping altogether by instead simply using [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot):

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(2,))
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
w = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.0], name="weights")

model = tf.tensordot(X, w, 1)
```

Finally, note that while the approach of splitting up the sample before passing it to the optimizer (in what is typically referred to as batching) works well for large datasets, in your case you could just as well pass the entire sample at once; that is, something that would amount to

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(50, 2))
Y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(50, 1))
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1], "float"), name="weights")

model = tf.matmul(X, w)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow((Y - model), 2))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10000):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trainX, Y: trainY.reshape((50, 1))})
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering the question. I got my code working and thanks for the additional info for passing the whole training data at a time.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).